# Linear Algebra Matrices, Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Hey I was asked a question I can't seem to understand can anyone help me?

Suppose that $T : \mathbb R^4 → \mathbb R^3$ is a linear transformation. Must it be the case that
$T(a, b, c, d) = (0, 0, 0)$ for some $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb R$? Must it be the case that $T(a, b, c, d) =
(1, 3, 2)$ for some $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb R$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What do you think that $T(0,0,0,0)$ is?

Comment: As implied by another comment, the first is a must but the second case is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any linear transformation $T: V \rightarrow W$, where $V$ and $W$ are vector spaces over the real numbers, we must have for all vectors $\mathbf{v} \in V$ and scalars $c \in \mathbb{R}$, that $T(c\mathbf{v}) = cT(\mathbf{v})$ (this is one of the two properties that define the "linear" part of the linear transformation). Knowing that $0\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{0}$, what does that imply for $T(\mathbf{0})$?

As for the second part of your question, consider the function $T: V \rightarrow W$ such that $T(\mathbf{v}) = \mathbf{0}$ for all $\mathbf{v} \in V$. Is it a linear transformation? What does it look like when $V = \mathbb{R}^4$ and $W = \mathbb{R}^3$?